# Node.js memory, GC and performance

Tags: performance, node.js, memory, garbage-collection

There are rumors that current Node.js (or, more exactly V8 GC) performs badly when there are lots of JS objects and memory used.

Can You please explain what exatly is the problem - lots of objects or lots of properties on one object (or array)?

Maybe there are some benchmarks, would be interesting to see actual code and numbers.

As far as I know the main problem - lots of properties on one object, not lots of objects itself (although I'm not sure). 
If so - would be the in-memory graph database (about couple of hundreds of properties on each node at max) a good case?

Also I heard that latest versions of V8 has improved GC and that it solved some parts of this problems - is this true, and when it will be available in Node.js?

Comment: Why is it closed as not constructive?